Django path doesn't match URL
This Django path:
path('/search/<str:q>', views.search, name="search")

doesn't match this url:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/akdbapp/search/?q=foo

Why not?
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/akdbapp/search/?q=foo
Using the URLconf defined in aksite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
akdbapp/ [name='index']
akdbapp/ /search/<str:q> [name='search']
akdbapp/ [name='detail']
akdbapp/ <int:artwork_id>/ [name='detail']
admin/
__debug__/
The current path, akdbapp/search/, didn’t match any of these.



Your url pattern expects /askdbapp/search/foo, not /askdbapp/search/?q=foo.

?q=foo is not part of the path, it's the querystring.
Your path should be
path('/search/', views.search, name="search")

and you should access q using
q = request.GET.get("q")

in your view.

Thanks Seljuk and Matija! That was the problem.  I didn't realize that the query string wasn't considered part of the URL. Cheers, H

@HarryS You may accept the answer by clicking the next mark next to it to help future visitors.
